# SKAction change the color of a SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, skaction, skshapenode

I am using the repeatActionForever method from SKAction to change the color of an SKShapeNode.
Here's my code:

```
SKShapeNode *ship = [SKShapeNode node];
[ship setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(-15, -15, 40, 17), 6.25, 6.25, nil)];
ship.fillColor = [SKColor redColor];
ship.glowWidth = 3;

[ship runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[
[SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor blueColor] colorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:0.5],
[SKAction waitForDuration:0.3],[SKAction colorizeWithColorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:0.5],
[SKAction colorizeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] colorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:0.5],
[SKAction waitForDuration:0.3],
[SKAction colorizeWithColorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:0.5],
[SKAction waitForDuration:0.3]]]]];
return ship; //because it's a method
```

It looks right to me but the ship doesn't change color. What am I doing wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In contrast to a `SKSpriteNode`, a `SKShapeNode` does not have a `color` property. So your `colorizeWithColor:` action won't work.

Take a look at this post on how to animate the `fillColor` and `strokeColor`: [SKShapeNode - Animate color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872556/skshapenode-animate-color-change)